# Simple XML variable returns "0"

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml, tumblr

Ok, so im working with tumblr's API and im using SimpleXMLElement with php and ive run into a problem.

Basically, when I call on a variable it just prints a zero.

for instance :

```
<?php echo $data->posts->post[0]->photo-url[5]; ?>
```

This just breaks the page, and when I leave out the [5] it just prints zero

I want to echo the photo-url with the number [5] but I cant get my head around this and its killing me. I just dont understand why it wont work.

Heres a sample of the simpleXMLElement print-out :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
```

(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0
        )

```
[posts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [type] => photo
            )

        [post] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 574166180
                                [url] => http://young-n-reckless.tumblr.com/post/574166180
                                [url-with-slug] => http://young-n-reckless.tumblr.com/post/574166180
                                [type] => photo
                                [date-gmt] => 2010-05-05 19:52:46 GMT
                                [date] => Wed, 05 May 2010 15:52:46
                                [unix-timestamp] => 1273089166
                                [format] => html
                                [reblog-key] => vc9EfT7d
                                [slug] => 
                                [tumblelog] => young-n-reckless
                                [bookmarklet] => true
                            )

                        [tumblelog] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [title] => Young & Reckless
                                        [name] => young-n-reckless
                                        [url] => http://young-n-reckless.tumblr.com/
                                        [timezone] => US/Eastern
                                        [avatar-url-16] => http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_16.png
                                        [avatar-url-24] => http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_24.png
                                        [avatar-url-30] => http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_30.png
                                        [avatar-url-40] => http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_40.png
                                        [avatar-url-48] => http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_48.png
                                        [avatar-url-64] => http://26.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_64.png
                                        [avatar-url-96] => http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_96.png
                                        [avatar-url-128] => http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_128.png
                                        [avatar-url-512] => http://29.media.tumblr.com/avatar_424f776dd55c_512.png
                                    )

                            )

                        [photo-link-url] => http://www.flickr.com/photos/katiemabey/3429588812/
                        [photo-url] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_500.jpg
                                [1] => http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_500.jpg
                                [2] => http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_400.jpg
                                [3] => http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_250.jpg
                                [4] => http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_100.jpg
                                [5] => http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l1w1qd7Zcg1qatgoto1_75sq.jpg
                            )

                    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.
Warren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element name has a dash in it, you need to wrap it like so:

```
<?php echo $data->posts->post[0]->{'photo-url'}[5]; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir!

Works perfect now. Really appreciate it. :)